# Powershell: creating functions (or aliases) for system commands

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make it easier to run certain things with certain users from powershell.

So first I calculate username and domain needed to run a specific command, which is no problem.

But then I want to be able to run a specific command with the calculated credentials, and this fails. I have already tried the following variants:

```
# this does not work yet (the command works, but the alias/function doesn't
# function aduc {"runas /user:$currentUserDomain\$adminUserNameTier0 dsa.msc"}
# function aduc {& "runas /user:$currentUserDomain\$adminUserNameTier0 dsa.msc"}
# function aduc {Invoke-Command -NoNewScope -ScriptBlock {runas /user:$currentUserDomain\$adminUserNameTier0 dsa.msc}}
# function aduc {Invoke-Command -NoNewScope -ScriptBlock {& "runas /user:$currentUserDomain\$adminUserNameTier0 dsa.msc"}}
```

Whenever I call "aduc", I get:

> aduc : The term 'runas /user:DOMAIN\USER dsa.msc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
> operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
> again.
> At line:1 char:1

(I put DOMAIN\USER in the error message for data protection, of course in reality we are using real, existing values)

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation I found this works:

```
$currentUserDomain = "contoso.com"
$adminUserNameTier0 = "contosodomainadmin"
function aduc {Invoke-Command -NoNewScope -ScriptBlock {runas /netonly /user:$currentUserDomain\$adminUserNameTier0 "mmc dsa.msc"}}
```

Now simply calling "aduc" will run the dsa ("Active Directory Users and Computers") mcc console as contoso\contosodomainadmin, asking for the password.

Question can be closed.